# Input from Microphone

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to take input from microphone and show that info in my edittext I have tried doing it in another activity it works fine but when I try to attach it with my login activity, as soon as it is done taking input from microphone my application crashes. On other activity it works fine it shows my input on my edittext but something is wrong with this activity and I can't find the solution

```
public class login extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private TextToSpeech tts;
    private EditText txv;

    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
                if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    int count=1;
                    if(count==1){
                    Intent in1=new Intent(login.this, Signup.class);
                    startActivity(in1);}
                    if(count==2)
                    {

                    }
                }
                return true;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
                if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());

                    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Your Device Don't Support Speech Input", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                return true;
            default:
                return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        txv = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tx2);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        findViewById(R.id.signup).setOnClickListener(this);
        initializeTextToSpeech();

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void initializeTextToSpeech() {
        tts= new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if(tts.getEngines().size()==0) {
                    Toast.makeText(login.this, "There's no TTS engine on your Device"
                            , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                } else{
                    tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                    tts.setSpeechRate(0.7f);
                    speak(" For new account Press volume up button 1 time and for login press volume up button 2 times.......To enter your username, press volume down button to activate your mic and speak your username");

                }
            }

        });

    }

    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        tts.shutdown();}

    public void speak(String message){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            tts.speak(message, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null,null);
        }
        else {
            tts.speak(message,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case 10:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                    ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    txv.setText(result.get(0));
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      switch (v.getId()){

          case R.id.signup:

              startActivity(new Intent(this, Signup.class));
              break;


      }
    }
}
```

Stacktrace

```
 --------- beginning of crash
2019-03-18 15:53:00.801 9755-9755/com.example.naji.finalyear E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.naji.finalyear, PID: 9755
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=10, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.naji.finalyear/com.example.naji.finalyear.login}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4053)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4096)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1516)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.naji.finalyear.login.onActivityResult(login.java:111)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6915)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4049)
```

Comment: _"my application crashes"_ Then you should post the stacktrace from the logcat output.

Comment: I have added stacktrace @Michael

Comment: txv = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tx2); Place This Sentence after setContentView(); --- :) ----

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `onCreate`, you need to call `setContentView` before using any `findViewById` calls.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
txv = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tx2);
```

These two lines just needed to be flipped around.